# Serverless Redshift connect via bastion server

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to ServerlessRedshift through python3.

There is a bastion server between my local and redshift. Please let me know if there is a way to connect to redshift through the bastion server (SSH Tunnel) with python3.

Comment: Looking at [Connecting to Amazon Redshift Serverless - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html), there are many ways to connect to Redshift Serverless. How is it configured in your environment? Is it connected to a VPC, or is it publicly accessible? Have you considered [Using the Amazon Redshift Data API - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html) instead of connecting via a normal database connection? How do your current applications connect to it?

Comment: This is a private VPC.
In tools such as datagrip, the connection is established through SSH tunneling.
However, I want to connect through a module such as python SSHTunnelForwarder, but it doesn't work.